# Stop Autoplay of Video Content in an iFrame

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, iframe

I am trying to load a video from a different website on my page in an `iframe` using the below code.

I am using the technique of basically just making the video player section visible on my page just like loading Youtube video in an iframe but just making the video player visible but I cannot make the video stop autoplaying.

I used `allow="autoplay 'none'" autoplay="0" autostart="0"` but still the video autoplays. Can someone please tell me how I can make the video stop autoplaying.

```
<div style="border: 3px solid white; overflow: hidden; margin: 5px auto; max-width: 736px;">
  <p>
    <iframe scrolling="no" src="https://VideoSource/media/ReleaseVideo" allow="autoplay 'none'" autoplay="0" autostart="0" style="font-size: 1rem; border-width: 0px; border-style: none; margin-left: -100px; height: 500px; margin-top: -75px; width: 926px;"></iframe>
  </p><br>
</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: You cannot access the content of a third-party cross-domain iframe. What you're attempting to do is not possible.

Comment: Well the content loads fine and the video as well plays fine..I just wanted to stop it from auto playing.

Comment: That's not a "just", your page does not have access to iframe content, it is a completely independent page for all intents and purposes _unless_ you set up [postMessage() interfacing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) to it. The fact that the iframe loads fine and plays video fine has nothing to do with whether the owning document has access or control over the iframe content. It doesn't, for most excellent security reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Use `autostart="false"` instead of `autostart="0"`.
Such that:

```
<div style="border: 3px solid white; overflow: hidden; margin: 5px auto; max-width: 736px;">
  <p>
    <iframe scrolling="no" src="https://VideoSource/media/ReleaseVideo" allow="autoplay 'none'" autoplay="0" autostart="false" style="font-size: 1rem; border-width: 0px; border-style: none; margin-left: -100px; height: 500px; margin-top: -75px; width: 926px;"></iframe>
  </p><br>
</div>
```